# Symfony2 - QueryBuilder error message

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

So, I'm going to try and explain the problem I have here :)

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Controller\MunkakController::AppBundle\Controller{closure}() must be an instance of AppBundle\Controller\EntityRepository, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given

This is the error message I get. This is the code that I try to run:

```
$formbe = $this->createFormBuilder($ujbeszab, ['attr' => ['id' => 'ujbeszabid']])
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('uj-beszab', array('szabid' => $szabid)))
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('munkatipusok', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle:Munkatipusok', 'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $rep) {
                $qb = $rep->createQueryBuilder('u');
                return $qb->orderBy('u.munkatipusok', 'ASC');
            }, 'empty_value' => null, 'label' => "Munkatípus", 'required' => false))   
            ->add('idopont', 'date', array('label' => "Időpontja", 'format' => 'yyyy.MM.dd', 'years' => range(date('Y') -10, date('Y') +10), 'required' => true))
            ->add('megjegyzes', 'textarea', array('label' => "Megjegyzés", 'required' => false))
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Létrehozás'))
            ->getForm();
```

It has some Hungarian variable names, basicly I'm trying to add a job to a database. You have to select the job type from a dropdown, enter the date('idopont'), you can also add a comment('megjegyzes'). The job types come from a different table, they come from the 'munkatipusok' table. So, what i'm trying to do is to be able to filter the shown jobs. I know I could show all the job types and then remove them from the select field with javascript, but that is risky, in case jscript doesn't run on the computer. So I want to filter server side, with a QueryBuilder.

Comment: did you forget the use statement ?

Comment: Sorry for being so stupid and dumb, and taking the storage space on your server :) Yea, I forgot "use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;" at the begining. I mean I thought that the person who originally wrote it put it there, cause he used the getRepository function on the Entity Manager. Thanks Sam ^^

Comment: cheers for posting this question and answer, storage space well used! i forgot the use statement as well. half of my errors are forgetting the use statements